# OpenStreetMap river boundaries cannot be queried

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm trying to download the river banks polygons from a region from OSM, using overpass API; when I try to query the river feature it doesn't appear in the results tab, neither as Neighbor feature or Enclosing feature (first image); if I select a region there broad rivers don't appear, but other water bodies do (second image). How can I access this data?.

Sample region query: https://www.openstreetmap.org/query?lat=25.0068&lon=89.5970

[image]

[image]

Comment: When querying for features, try to click on the edge of the river, not in the middle.

Comment: That's the answer!

Answer (score 2):

When querying for features, try to click on the edge of the river, not in the middle. The query mechanism only searches for features in the near surrounding (except for administrative boundaries). Since rivers are defined by their outline, the river feature is only found at the edge of the river but not in the middle of it.